# C# query in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, arraylist, visual-studio-2015

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2015.
I have a `List<MagicItem> magicItemList` and I'm trying to do a simple query using Linq to fetch an Object that matches the Id that the user inputs.
This is my code:

```
int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

var query = from MagicItem magicItem in magicItemList
                where magicItem.Id == itemId
                select magicItem;
```

The thing that confuses me is that `query`'s type is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`, so I can't fetch any of its attributes as a normal Object.

Is there a way to cast it so I can use it as a normal Object? Thanks in advance.

This is my MagicItem Class:

```
class MagicItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int StockLevel { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirstOrDefault()` to get your item. If there is no item with the id you will get null. That's why you have to check for null.

```
var item = magicItemList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = itemId);
if(item != null)
{
    //do something with item
}
```

With your code you are getting a collection because you are checking one property and you'll get all items in your collection which are matching this property.

For more information have a look at the [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 0):

It is going to fetch all instances that match your condition `magicItem.Id == itemId`.
If you are certain that that will be a single item, I recommend using `query.FirstOrDefault()` to get that item.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you will not *per se* **obtain one element**: at code level it is unknown that the **id is unique**.

You can use [`.First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`.FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) to obtain the **first element** that matches the condition:

```
var query = (from MagicItem magicItem in magicItemList
                where magicItem.Id == itemId
                select magicItem).First();
```